# create Box in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make HTML page which contain a picture and a green box below.
the green box contains a text and h1 text and more text.

I wrote this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html;charset=windows-1255" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>site</title>
<style type="text/css">
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
  } 
main {
    background-color:#F7FDEB;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    }
userChoice {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    background-color:#BCCE98;
    width:250px;height:100px
    }
img.GeneratedImage {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width:250px;height:100px;margin:20px;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;
}

</style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl" align="center">
    <main dir="rtl" align="center">
      <img dir="rtl" align="center" src="http://www.html.am/images/samples/remarkables_queenstown_new_zealand-300x225.jpg" alt="" class="GeneratedImage"><br>
      <userChoice align="center" dir="rtl">
                    23:19 ‎18/‎08/‎2015
                    <h1>fdfgbdf</h1>
                    sdfs
      </userChoice >
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

but it's doesn't show the green box.
I tried to resolve this problem using div but didn't succeeded.  what should be the problem?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you create new elements (`userChoice`, `main`) instead of using existing ones (`section`, `div`) and giving those a class or id?

Comment: Also `align` has been deprecated.

Comment: So what to use instand?

Comment: there isn't reason but to make the code simple and understandable. why not to use?

Comment: It is making your code less understandable in my opinion. :) I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcjc08o4/) with your code, and I do get a green box. Where is your problem exactly?

Comment: It makes two green box - the date is in green box and the "sdfs" text in another green box, the text in H1 doesn't in green box. I want to see one big box which contain all the element.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `align` has been deprecated and you should use other centering techniques such as `text-align:center` and `margim:auto`.

Also, while custom elements are possible, general use is not recommended as browser support cannot be guaranteed and you may not get the effect you were looking for.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  }

.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
main {
  background-color: #F7FDEB;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.userChoice {
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-color: #BCCE98;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
img.GeneratedImage {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<main dir="rtl">
  <img src="http://www.html.am/images/samples/remarkables_queenstown_new_zealand-300x225.jpg" alt="" class="GeneratedImage" />

  <div dir="rtl" class="userChoice rtl">23:19 ‎18/‎08/‎2015
    <h1>forwards</h1>
    sdfs
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Not gonna post another answer with almost the same code as you - you can use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcjc08o4/1/) as external link if you want. Only thing I changed as well was to use a `section` with class `main` instead of a `main`-element.

Comment: Thank you. Why the sdfs text outside from the box?

Comment: Fixed...the `h1` was pushing it out. Added a quick margin reset.

Answer (score 0):

Put this where the css goes:

```
.green-box {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: solid green 2px;
   margin-top: 100px;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 46%;
}
```

And for the html you can do something like this:

```
<div class="green-box">
</div>
```

Adjust the css settings appropriately to get the correct dimensions

Comment: Thank you. but still what is the problem with the way I use/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
  } 
main {
    background-color:#F7FDEB;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    }
userChoice {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    background-color:#BCCE98;
    width:250px;
  display: block; margin: 10px;padding: 10px
    }
img.GeneratedImage {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width:250px;height:100px;margin:20px;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body dir="rtl" align="center">
    <main dir="rtl" align="center">
      <img dir="rtl" align="center" src="http://www.html.am/images/samples/remarkables_queenstown_new_zealand-300x225.jpg" alt="" class="GeneratedImage"><br>
      <userChoice align="center" dir="rtl">
                    23:19 ‎18/‎08/‎2015
                    <h1>fdfgbdf</h1>
                    sdfs
      </userChoice >
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

i think this is what you are trying..

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use `align` attribute. Updated - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucbzs4su/)

Comment: Please update the fiddle to remove the `align` attribute, it's deprecated and not a nice example. Use `margin: auto;` or `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. While I agree that `align` shouldn't be used it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes In the answers section I have provided the solution. Also we should suggest what the standard. and leave the choice up to the user what to implement.

Comment: @OnkarDeshpande I agree we should advise, but this doesn't answer the question and should really be a comment.